# JTable is coloring every cell when I only want it to color specific cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
private class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{           
    String[][] data;    

    public ColorRenderer(String[][] data)
    {
        this.data = new String[data.length][data[0].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            for(int g = 0; g < data[0].length; g++)
            {
                this.data[i][g] = data[i][g];       
            }
        }

    }       

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);            

        if(row < data.length - 3 && data[row][col].equals(""))
        {               
            c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }

        return c;
    }       
}
```

`data` is the array of data that fills in the JTable. The table is mostly full of strings but has some empty strings. I want to color in the cells that have empty strings only, but not the last three rows.

For some reason though, it is currently indiscriminately coloring in my whole table, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your override of `DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent`, add an else part after the if statement:

```
if(row < data.length - 3 && data[row][col].equals(""))
    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
else 
    c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
```

The default table cell renderer uses one component, which is used to render the contents of each cell. Once you change its color, it'll remain that color until that color is explicitly changed.

Comment: this answer is not logical, this should not be the reason

Comment: @hunter Oh :) it's highly logical and indeed the answer as the questioner will find out soon.

Comment: @hunter Read the `Implementation note` in the [DefaultTableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) documentation, it'll say the same thing in more words.

Comment: yes that documentation is totally fine. i thought that super.getTableCellRendererComponent should set the correct background color. according to the source code it should be like that.

Comment: @hunter Well, I have never inspected the source code, I've only seen the results when you have code that only sets color in specific circumstances like the OP. It will remain the last set color for the next cell. Perhaps there exist different implementations of that class that behave differently, only I have never seen it behave other than what I described.

Comment: @hunter Looking at the source code, I'm seeing `setForeground` and `setBackground` methods set `unselectedForeground` and `unselectedBackground` members, which are used to initialize the JLabel's color in getTableCellRendererComponent (if selected is false that is).

Comment: thanks TT, I appreciate your answer and hope it will help the OP, that's the ultimate goal of this community. at least OP will dig deep into the java source code.

Comment: thanks! i suspected something like this was going on but it wasnt hitting me how i should deal with it

Comment: (1+), yes this is indeed the way the default renderer works. The background is NOT automatically reset every time a cell is painted.